# Exclude single page from function

Tags: single

```
//wraps the permalink around each thumbnail
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

  $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
  return $html;
 }
```

As the comment says, wraps the permalink around each thumbnail, but I'd like to exclude the link on single pages so I tried

```
//wraps the permalink around each thumbnail
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );

function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {

  $html = '<a href="' . get_permalink( $post_id ) . '" title="' . esc_attr( get_post_field( 'post_title', $post_id ) ) . '">' . $html . '</a>';
  return $html;
  else {
  if( is_single() ) { 
      $html = '';
      return $html;

      }

      }
}
```

It breaks my site.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is not the way functions work. You can't tack part of an `if/else` query onto the end of a function... at least that kinda looks like what you are doing. Or maybe you're are trying to us an `else` without the `if`... Anyway, the syntax is badly broken.

Here is a cleaned up version that should do what you intended your function to do (I think).

```
//wraps the permalink around each thumbnail
add_filter( 'post_thumbnail_html', 'my_post_image_html', 10, 3 );
function my_post_image_html( $html, $post_id, $post_image_id ) {
  if(!is_single()) { 
    $html = '<a href="'.get_permalink($post_id).'" title="'.esc_attr( get_post_field('post_title',$post_id)).'">'.$html.'</a>';
  }
  return $html;
}
```